# How to utilize C# attributes and reflection to inject/force late bindings on marked objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection, attributes, late-binding

I love design patterns, the problem is that some can be really tedious to implement.
For example, decorating an object that has 20+ members is just plain annoying.

So, I wanted to create a nice library of design patterns to be applied to classes (either as base classes or attributes) to make implementation of these patterns much quicker and eaiser.

The problem is...I'm not quite sure where to start - because I am mostly unfamiliar with attributes and reflection.

---

I would like to utilize attributes to mark Singletons (similar to the Export tag), Multitons, and Decorators...if at all possible.  But I don't even know where to start in order to create a singleton attribute that alters the functionality of its instances.

My limited research has led me to believe that using reflection/late binding through an attribute and gaining access to all marked classes in the assembly, would allow you to hack together a singleton...but I'm still not entirely sure how that would be done.

A framework I found, called [Ninject](http://ninject.org/download) 1.0, created a Singleton attribute - but the library is so extensive and undocumented, that I am currently unable to follow its logic.

---

I feel like a library with this sort of functionality would be a great contribution to many developers out there.  So, it would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide some sample code that gets me pointed in the right direction to create one of these patterns as an attribute - whose code isn't overly involved.  Or if someone would be willing to walk me through Ninject's singleton attribute implementation so I may work off of that...

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Try writing a sample of what this would look like in code.  On an unrelated point, I'm a little dubious myself.  I recall going through a period when I wanted to systematize my understanding of design patterns into a sub-framework, and it was essentially a waste of time.  Much more valuable has been just using them in my daily work.  But hey, go for it.  I'd never discourage experimentation, just want to encourage you to make vague ideas more concrete.

Comment: I don't know if a Singleton attribute will actually reduce your work, but it's a cool idea. For the Decorator pattern, you could use reflection to replicate all the target's public members, then either call them with more reflection or type your decorator as `dynamic` in order to access them. The problem is that you'll lose all the benefits of static typing, including Intellisense. If your target class has so many members that it's worth it, you might need to refactor anyway.

Comment: You could probably try improving Ninject's documentation on Github. Ninject provides an excellent framework for this already. That being said, doesn't mean you can't make a better wheel.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a slight confusion on what design patterns mean.

A pattern is really a *common way* of doing things, designed to solve a *particular problem*.

You don't really use patterns for patterns' sake.  More patterns usage doesn't automatically means good.  You use a pattern to solve a type *problem* -- and hopefully that pattern is the recognized best-practice way to solve that problem.  Don't try to appy a pattern to your code because you *can*.

Now, after all this, it can really be seen that what you are planning to do is not the right way of going about implementing pattern(s).  You don't mark code with attributes etc. and then call them patterns.  The pattern **is** your code.  Your code **is** the pattern.  For example, you don't mark a publisher/subscriber pattern on a class unless it really implements publish/subscribe functionalities.  For example, you don't mark a class with "Singleton" and then it becomes a singleton pattern; using the Singleton pattern requires you to code your program (and your classes) around that design.

You may, however, mark code or classes with certain attributes that can *aid* in *checking* whether the code/classes conform to a particular pattern.

For example, you may implement a type checker that goes through all your class, check if anything is marked "publisher" and see if that class implements the "IPublisher" interface.  Or your type checker can check if any class is marked "Singleton" whether the constructor allows construction of more than one instance at any one time.

But attributes and reflection is typically not the tools to *implement* a pattern.

In C#, where there is no multiple inheritance, the way you implement patterns is sometimes through the base class only.  For example, you may implement a "singleton" pattern by declaring a "SingletonObject" base class which limits itself to only one instantiation.  Then you derive any class that you want to be singletons from this base class.  For example, you may implement a "publish/subscribe" pattern by declaring IPublisher and ISubscriber interfaces.

Now, if you really just want to just use the Decorator pattern on C# classes (as per the title of your question), what you are looking for is an automatic wrapper object generator.  You can based your wrapper on an ExpandoObject, loop through the properties of the base object, and add properties to the ExpandoObject that simply delegates back to the base object.  Then add new properties to the ExpandoObject on top of your base object.  Voila!  You get your auto-Decorator-Pattern wrapper class generator.